# Filter dates by particular column value

Tags: r

I am trying to filter dates with a particular offsetdate value from calendar days dataframe.

Dataframe calendardays:

```
calendardays <- as.data.frame(as.Date(seq(as.Date("2019-01-03"), as.Date("2022-12-31"), by="days")))
colnames(calendardays)<- c("Date")
```

DF2:

```
     LC    Custcode       Date      offsetdate
    RM11    IN007543    2019-10-03  2
    WK15    IN007543    2019-10-03  3
```

In DF2, for each row there is a offsetdate which means that I want to find x no. of dates from the Date which is mentioned in  DF2 corresponding to that LC CustCode from Dataframe calendardays.

Output:

```
     LC    Custcode       Date      
    RM11    IN007543    2019-10-03
    RM11    IN007543    2019-10-04
    WK15    IN007543    2019-10-03
    WK15    IN007543    2019-10-04
    WK15    IN007543    2019-10-05
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do we need `calendardays` ? We can directly expand `DF2` using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

DF2 %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date), 
         seq_day = map2(Date, Date + offsetdate, seq, by = "1 day")) %>%
  unnest(seq_day) %>%
  select(-Date, -offsetdate)

#  LC    Custcode seq_day   
#  <fct> <fct>    <date>    
#1 RM11  IN007543 2019-10-03
#2 RM11  IN007543 2019-10-04
#3 RM11  IN007543 2019-10-05
#4 WK15  IN007543 2019-10-03
#5 WK15  IN007543 2019-10-04
#6 WK15  IN007543 2019-10-05
#7 WK15  IN007543 2019-10-06
```

Comment: Yeah, we can skip calendar days. 
And Here we just need dates from date which is already present in DF2. For eg in RM11 & IN007543 we just need 2 dates 2019-10-03 & 2019-10-04. From the current dates offset dates need to be found

Comment: Got it changed logic to: Date + offsetdate - 1

Answer (score 3):

Expand DF2 using ix and then increment the Date field.  No packages are used.

```
ix <- rep(1:nrow(DF2), DF2$offsetdate) # 1,1,2,2,2
DF2rep <- transform(DF2[ix, ], Date = Date + sequence(DF2$offsetdate) - 1)[-4]
```

This already gives the output shown in the question but if you need to check whether the dates also appear in calendardays this will only keep dates in DF2rep that are also in calendardays.

```
DF2rep[DF2rep$Date %in% calendardays$Date, ]
```

### Note

DF2 in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "     LC    Custcode       Date      offsetdate
    RM11    IN007543    2019-10-03  2
    WK15    IN007543    2019-10-03  3"
DF2 <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
DF2$Date <- as.Date(DF2$Date)
```

Comment: Getting this error: Error in DF2$offsetdate : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.
What could be the reason

Comment: Start a fresh R session, copy and paste the code in the Note and then copy and paste the code in the body of the answer. Presumably you have done something that you haven't shown us and we don't know what you did to introduce an error.